# Get type from generic type fullname

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to get type from generic type fullname like that :

```
var myType = Type.GetType("MyProject.MyGenericType`1[[MyProject.MySimpleType, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]");
```

But it seems to not work with generics types like that...

What is the good method to do that ?

Comment: You meant to close the "<", right? If not, that's the first error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the assembly qualified name, `Type.GetType` works only for `mscorlib` types. In your example you has defined the AQN only for the embedded type argument.

```
// this returns null:
var type = Type.GetType("MyProject.MyGenericType`1[[MyProject.MySimpleType, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]");

// but this works:
var type = Type.GetType("MyProject.MyGenericType`1[[MyProject.MySimpleType, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
```

Your original type string will work though, if you use `Assembly.GetType` instead of `Type.GetType`:

```
var myAsm = typeof(MyGenericType<>).Assembly;
var type = myAsm.GetType("MyProject.MyGenericType`1[[MyProject.MySimpleType, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]");
```

Comment: Your first solution seems to work ! But how to get the fullname of my generic type with AQN for generic type ?

Comment: Take a look at my reply. You can specify it for generic type as you would normally and for generic arguments you wrap them in `[]`.

Comment: `typeof(MyGenericType<MySimpleType>).AssemblyQualifiedName` returns the AQN

Comment: Perfect, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var myType = Type.GetType("MyProject.MyGenericType`1, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]");
```

Then use `MakeGenericType()`:

```
var finalType = myType.MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("MyProject.MySimpleType"));
```

Alternatively, if the open generic type can be determined at compile type, you can simply use the `typeof` operator with `<>`:

```
var myType = typeof(MyProject.MyGenericType<>);
var finalType = myType.MakeGenericType(typeof(MyProject.MySimpleType));
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172334(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have only the string of generic type with parameter of generic type implemented : "MyProject.MyGenericType`1[[MyProject.MySimpleType, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"

Comment: @k4st0r42, I revised my answer accordingly. But, if `string` is all you have, then @kiziu solution might be easier.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to try "reverse engineering".

When you call eg.

```
typeof(List<int>)
```

you get

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

You can then use this as a template, so calling

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]")
```

will give you proper type.

Number after ` is the number of generic arguments, which are then listed in `[]`using comma as a separator.

EDIT: If you take a look at `FullName` of any type, you will see how to handle types while also specifying assembly. That will require wrapping the type in extra `[]`, so the end result would be

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib")
```

Of course, you can specify also the version, culture and public key token, if you need that.

Comment: Sorry, it was an error of copy/paste. I edited my message... This is the method i use but it doesn't work with my types...

Comment: Are you sure you specified the type names correctly? Can you get both types separately using `Type.GetType()`?